# Kids show from the early 2000’s with a blonde teen that would turn into an electric superhero

Tags: story-identification, tv

This show would have been on in the early 2000’s and I remember it not being animated. There was a blonde teen that would turn into an electric superhero, I believe the colors were blue. Everytime I try to find it I come up with Ace Lightning but I don’t believe that is it.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this? Any plot lines or specific things that happen in the episodes? Any of the other characters? Please [edit] your question to include everything you remember.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t remember much else about it, I was maybe 5 or 6 watching it

Comment: Could it have been a Power Rangers show?

Comment: I don’t think so, I watched power rangers as a kid and this was different

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Could it have been The Secret World of Alex Mack?

Comment: Just to check, you're not thinking of [Static Shock](https://imgix-media.wbdndc.net/cms/filer_public/98/ca/98ca6255-eb84-47cf-b2cc-db4e7321c718/showtime.jpg) (image from DC Universe), are you? While the titular teenage hero, Static, was black, his sidekick/plucky best friend/tech-wiz-mcguffin was a blonde kid named Richie, who later became a 'co-hero' named Gear alongside Static. Static's costume was blue and black.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be "Misfits of Science?"  It was a TV show that was on from 1985-1986 so a little earlier than you suggested so maybe it was a rerun.  One of the misfits had electrical powers.  He could hurl lightning bolts and run in a sort of "electrical form" at high speeds.